# Remote Debian install instead of Ubuntu

Tags: installation, debian, remote

I have server with Ubuntu and can work with it through ssh. Is it possible to install Debian remotely?

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert the system from Ubuntu to Debian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [HOWTO - Install Debian Onto a Remote Linux System](http://www.underhanded.org/papers/debian-conversion/remotedeb.html)

Comment: I've done it! =)